# Get number of objects in an array fails for unspecified reason

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

If I have a JavaScript object like this and I would like to get number of objects in an array how would I do it? I've tried using `.length` but it doesn't works.

```
[
    { name: 'Alex', age: '15'},
    { name: 'Ben', age: '20'},
    { name: 'John', age: '43'}
]
```

I've done this one let's says this array is called 'names'. I tried to count number of objects in an array `names.length` but it doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" in what way, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
var names= [
    { name = 'Alex', age = '15'},
    { name = 'Ben', age = '20'},
    { name = 'John', age = '43'}
]
```

to this:

```
var names = [
    { name: 'Alex', age: '15'},
    { name: 'Ben', age: '20'},
    { name: 'John', age: '43'}
]
```

and it will work. You can get the number of objects with `names.length`.

Comment: Sorry I put up a bad example I didn't meant to use = I meant to use : but my problem is I want to count number of objects in an array.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: What error? See this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3uvjd65c/

Answer (score -1):

There should not be `=` in JSON,

Comment: I guess you mean "in an JavaScript object literal". Anyway, the OP now claims this was not the problem.